# Effect of Moving Charge on Current of Superconductor

Tags: electromagnetism, superconductivity

Suppose you have a superconductor that is in a superconducting state and holding a constant current. If moving charges pass within the superconductor's magnetic field and get accelerated by its magnetic force, would the current in the superconductor decrease?

Comment: This is a good conceptual question. Look forward to the answer. Gets us away from equations for a sec to increase intuition - without being underspecified..

Comment: The magnetic force on a moving charge is perpendicular to its velocity, so it does no work. This would mean no energy taken from the superconductor, so no change.

Comment: @Peter So it's not possible for the superconductor to produce a force on the moving charge? What about in another configuration like a superconducting solenoid?

Comment: It produces a force, but the force does no work. It only changes the direction of motion of the charge. There would be a reaction force on the superconductor, but I assumed that would be held rigidly in place.

Comment: @Peter So the superconductor would move the charge in a perpendicular direction but when the opposing force impacts the superconductor it absorbs it?

Comment: I assumed the mounting (hence the planet) would.